# Call function named functionA from class component ClassComponentA in file fileA in function component B in file functionComponentA in REACT 17

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, methods, components

I have two components, one is a class component and the other one is a function component.
I want to call method in functionComponentA placed in classComponentA.
I did it by sending the method in props.
I do not want to do it this way

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import functionComponentA from './functionComponentA'
class ClassComponentA extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            coolVariable : 1
    }

    functionA= () => {
        return "something"
}
    render(){

    const functionComponentA = <functionComponentA method= {this.doStuff.bind()}/>
    return functionComponentA
    }
}
export default ClassComponentA

//the code below is in a different file
import ClassComponentA from './ClassComponentA'
function FunctionComponentA (props){
    return <input onBlur= {event => {ClassComponentA.functionA()}/>
}
export default FunctionComponentA
```

when I do as in code above, I get ClassComponentA__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.functionA is not a function
I do not want to send the function as a props but I want to call it from the file where the other component is placed. Can it be done in any way and what am I doing wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import functionComponentA from './functionComponentA'
class ClassComponentA extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            coolVariable : 1
    }

    functionA= () => {
        return "something"
}
    render(){

    const functionComponentA = <functionComponentA method= {this.doStuff.bind()}/>
    return functionComponentA
    }
}
export default ClassComponentA

//code below is from a different file
function FunctionComponentA (props){
    return <input onBlur= {event => {props.functionA()}/>
}
export default FunctionComponentA
```

Comment: I think `functionComponentA` should start with a capital letter. `functionA` is only available after "instantiation"

Answer (score 0):

You have many typos and few basic mistakes:

```
// typo: functionComponentA, no need to bind if you use arrow function
// there is no function doStuff, rename from functionA
<FunctionComponentA method={this.doStuff}/>

// call method() as the prop name and not functionA().
function FunctionComponentA (props){
    return <input onBlur={()=> props.method()} />
}
```

Finally the code should look like so:

```
class ClassComponentA extends Component {
  doStuff = () => {
    console.log("hello");
  };
  render() {
    return <FunctionComponentA method={this.doStuff} />;
  }
}

function FunctionComponentA(props) {
  return <input onBlur={props.method} />;
}
```